# Migrating code from Qt free version to Qt Commercial

Tags: qt, licensing

Friends I am in dilemma.

**None of the threads explain if [and how ] i can migrate an application from Qt free version to Qt commercial.**

Me and my friends started developing an application using Qt[freely available] for learning .
We have created a good application and think we can sell it for pocket money.

The application does not modify any of the Qt source[we are not that good programmers :P] and we dynamically linked also.

I want to know how can i migrate it to Qt Commercial [**since it protects from giving my source code**].

First things first

a) **can i migrate an application[not distributed in any form] written in Qt free version to Qt commercial.**

b) will i have to re-write the application again in Qt commercial version or i can use my source files from old project and migrate to new Qt commercial project.

c) are there any API difference between Qt commercial libraries and Qt LGPL libraries that will make porting difficult/impossible. we still plan to have dynamic linking

d) i hope all Qt LGPL features are supported in Qt Commercial.

e) is there any complex legal thing i need to know. i only understand with LGPL we have to distribute code / object code + dynamic linking but in Qt commercial we dont have to.

If it is possible and legal then only we will buy Commercial License[expensive huh] ?

Comment: AFAIK the code base is pretty much the same. Mabye there are some features you can use only in the commercial version, but then, coming from the free version, you wouldn't have used them anyway. So why do you not simply compile it and see if it works? It should IMO. Also if you purchase a license, you are sure to get some helpline you can contact which probably can answer your question much better.

Comment: Just use the trial option first and just build and compile in that, think everything should work fine since its like the same with extra stuff, i did the exact same to test out the charting library but when they came back with a price we decided to bail on the idea!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you go to qt.digia.com click Try&Buy and then Download and Install Qt Enterprise.
You'll see if you can port it before actually buying a license.

And for licensing questions I would suggest to contact then directly. I guess they would give you all the answers you need and try to help you with any problems you run in to.

Answer (score 2):

The core is basically the same. So you can compile your existing code by enterprise version with no change. The only reason for the commercial license is if you need commercial support or you are shipping on an embedded platform like a cellphone.

Qt Enterprise has some more features and tools like Charts, Qt purchasing, Qt Quick Compiler, Boot2Qt and some others.

Comment: It's better than that. You don't need to recompile. The commercial and open source Qt are binary compatible :)

Answer (score 0):

I see two really big issues:

- Not understanding the terms of the commercial license you plan on using.
- Not understanding the terms of the LGPL you develop under: they are nothing like what you state.

The terms of the commercial Qt license either expressly prohibit what you have done, or it is implied/understood that what you did is a NO-NO. Your project is now legally tainted and you can't ever apply the commercial license to it unless you buy the licenses for all the developers that participated in the development. They'd go broke long ago if everyone was as "clever" as you are.

The LGPL does *not* force you to release *your* source code. All it forces you to do is to let the *end user* re-link with binary-compatible Qt of their choice, and for you to allow access to the sources of Qt you used. If you use a release Qt, all you need to provide, on request, is the .zip of the Qt version(s) you redistribute. Since you link dynamically with Qt, there's nothing further you need to do here.

The only binary differences between commercial and open source Qt are in the license markers. There's literally nothing you need to do to link your code with a commercial Qt. Just swap out the DLLs and you're done.

I'm not a lawyer.